# Makefile with generic intermediate rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that works that looks like this:

```
TARGET:=prog
SOURCES:=a.c b.c
CFLAGS:=-Wall -g -O2

OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

The only variables that the user needs to change are the target name and the sources required to build it.  The objects that need to be generated are automatically determined from the sources.  I would like to extend this to support multiple targets, each with its own list of sources.  I'm having trouble getting the syntax right, though.  This is the general idea:

```
TARGETS:=prog1 prog2
SOURCES_prog1:=a.c b.c
SOURCES_prog2:=a.c c.c
CFLAGS:=-Wall -g -O2

OBJECTS_$@=$(SOURCES_$@:%.c=%.o)

$(TARGETS): $(OBJECTS_$@)
    gcc -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

But I can't get the object list to be generated correctly.  I'm also unsure how to write the `clean` rule to clean all of the objects.  Is this possible?

Comment: Don't have time to write up more at the moment but for things like this you need to dynamically define targets/etc. with [`$(eval)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) and loops (and probably [Canned Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes). Alternatively (or possibly additionally) [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion). And unless you keep a list of all the objects/targets somewhere (or can generate it again) your `clean` rule won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary ways that I see to do this.

The first involves dynamically creating the target/prerequisite mappings using the [`$(eval)` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function).

```
TARGETS:=prog1 prog2
SOURCES_prog1:=a.c b.c
SOURCES_prog2:=a.c c.c
CFLAGS:=-Wall -g -O2

$(TARGETS):
        gcc -o $@ $^

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(eval OBJECTS_$t := $(SOURCES_$t:.c=.o))$(eval $t: $(OBJECTS_$t)))
```

The second involves using [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).

```
TARGETS:=prog1 prog2
SOURCES_prog1:=a.c b.c
SOURCES_prog2:=a.c c.c
CFLAGS:=-Wall -g -O2

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(TARGETS): $$(OBJECTS_$$@)
        gcc -o $@ $^

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(eval OBJECTS_$t := $(SOURCES_$t:.c=.o)))
```

In either case the `clean` target becomes:

```
clean:
        rm -f $(TARGETS) $(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(OBJECTS_$t))
```